# datagridview with datasource and combobox

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, datacolumn

I have a datagridview with a datasource attached to it made of a custom datatable:

DataTable:
    0 = Dictionary
    1 = string
    2 = string

the datagridview is editable, however for column 0 I need to show a combobox instead of a text field.  How do I go about achieving this?

```
internal Dictionary<int, string> products_list = new Dictionary<int, string>();
products_list.Add(0, "Test Product 1");
products_list.Add(1, "Test Product 2");


lines.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Product", products_list.GetType()));
lines.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("QTY", typeof(int)));
lines.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));

dgvQuoteLines.DataSource = lines;
dgvQuoteLines.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

*** UPDATE ***
I have now managed to add the combobox to the datagridview but sadly the datasource isn't working!

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colbox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
colbox.DataPropertyName = "0";
dgvQuoteLines.Columns.Add(colbox);
```

Comment: `colbox.DataPropertyName = "Product";`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel already tried that didn't work :(

Comment: Make sure to set the **.DataPropertyName** before setting the **DataSource**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colbox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
colbox.DataSource = products_list.ToList();
colbox.ValueMember = "Key";
colbox.DisplayMember = "Value";
dgvQuoteLines.Columns.Add( colbox );
```

Look at the [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx) class.

Comment: any ideas how to default the combobox to the first index?

Comment: You should probably add a new question for that.  You might get more responses.  I think I've answered your original question.

Comment: MSDN documentation is horrible. For example:   

"Gets or sets a string that specifies the property or column from which to retrieve strings for display in the combo boxes."   

All they had to say was: "The name of the column whose contents you want to display in the combobox" But I could not decipher the Hieroglyph that describes the ValueMember property.

Answer (score 1):

colBox.DataSource = products_list.Values.ToList();

?

What do you want to show up in the combobox?

Comment: the combobox should show the string from the dictionary and have a value of the int

Comment: Also that brings back : Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource

Comment: Kind of, the selectbox now works but the value when using dgvQuoteLines.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value; returns the string not the int

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
          string str4 = "select * from tblDepartment";
         DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colbox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
         colbox.DataSource = clsKetnoi.clsKetnoi.LayDuLieu(str4);
         colbox.Name = "Department";
         colbox.HeaderText  = "Department";
         colbox.ValueMember = "IDDepartment";
         colbox.DisplayMember = "DepartmentName";
         dgvDevice.Columns.Add(colbox);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).