# C# set datasource for combobox in datagridview

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, combobox

I have two tables, Units and Frequencies in an old program. frequency table has a foreign key to units table, A datagridview set it's datasource to units table. I want add a combobox to this datagridview contains frequencies.

select units

```
var data = context.Units.Where(u => u.Center.center_name.Trim() == cmbCenters.Text.Trim()).ToList();

// my datagridview
dgResult.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgResult.Columns.Clear();

....
....

if (chkRx.Checked)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn rxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    rxColumn.Name = "RX";
    rxColumn.ValueMember = "unitID";
    rxColumn.DispalyMember = "rxfreq";
    rxColumn.Datasource = context.Frequencies.ToList();
    dgResult.Columns.Add(rxColumn);
}
if (chkTx.Checked)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn txColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    txColumn.Name = "TX";
    txColumn.ValueMember = "unitID";
    txColumn.DispalyMember = "txfreq";
    txColumn.Datasource = context.Frequencies.ToList();
    dgResult.Columns.Add(txColumn);
}

dgResult.DataSource = data;
```

UPDATE:

I changed my code, but all frequencies shows in combobox not only frequecies for this unitID in each row.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656599/datagridview-with-datasource-and-combobox

Comment: @MethodMan are you mean i  must search for each data and create list of frequencies for each row unit and bind that to combobox.

Comment: what are you talking about I don't understand you.. are you familiar with `<ItemTemplates>`

Comment: each row must have a combobox contains of frequencies of each row unitID.

Comment: @MethodMan update qustion

Answer (score 0):

```
if (chkRx.Checked)`
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn rxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    rxColumn.Name = "RX";
    //rxColumn.DataPropertyName = "BRxs";
    var datafrequencies =context.Frequencies.ToList();
    rxColumn.DataSource = datafrequencies;
    rxColumn.ValueMember = "frequencyId";
    rxColumn.DisplayMember = "frequencyName";
    dgResult.Columns.Add(rxColumn);
}
dgResult.DataSource = data;`
```

you   search for each data  of frequencies in row

```
  private void dgResult_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
      {
        DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl comboControl = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        if (comboControl != null)
        {
            //Set the DropDown style to get an editable ComboBox
            if (comboControl.DropDownStyle != ComboBoxStyle.DropDown)
            {

                comboControl.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
                //int r = dgvconn.CurrentRow.Index;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i test this but its add all frequencies not only frequencies for this unit ineach row

Comment: var datafrequencies =context.Frequencies.ToList();rxColumn.DataSource = datafrequencies;

Comment: DataGridViewComboBoxColumn txColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                txColumn.Name = "TX";
                txColumn.DisplayMember = "Txfhertz";
                txColumn.ValueMember = "bid";
                txColumn.DataSource = context.Frequences.AsQueryable().ToList();

Comment: i use tha above code but show all data yet not only this row frequencies, and how editingcontriolshowing help me for this , i dont understand that part of your answer

Comment: The event on datagridview 
            //Set the DropDown style to get an editable ComboBox, search and filter